# Access $rootScope in AngularJS View

Tags: angularjs

How do I access $rootScope in my AngularJS views?

component with controller

```
angular.
  module('users').
  component('users', {
    templateUrl: 'components/users/users-template.html',
    controller: ['$http', "$scope", "$rootScope", function UsersController($http, $scope, $rootScope) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/users').then(function(response) {
        $rootScope.users = response.data;
      });

      $scope.addUser = function(e) {
        var $button = angular.element(e.target);
        $button.next('.modal').toggleClass('invisible')
      };
    }]
  });
```

If I change $rootScope to $scope it works. I thought it should work similarly with $rootScope?

View

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Users</h1>
  {{users}}
  <div class="users-list row" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <dl>
        <dt>First Name: </dt>
        <dd>{{user.first_name}}</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
   ommited for brevity
```

Answer (score 0):

By Default $scope inherits from $rootScope. You can check the following ways.

```
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('test', []);
      app.controller("testCtrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope",
    function ($scope, $rootScope) {
      $rootScope.way1 = 'By default $scope inherits $rootScope.';
       $rootScope.way2 = 'use $root in interpolation.';
       $rootScope.way3 = '$rootScope can be injected on $scope variable';
       $scope.test=$rootScope;
    }]);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
     <p>1.  {{way1}}</p>
    <p>2.  {{$root.way2}}</p>
    <p>2.  {{test.way3}}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is the plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/msbWwlxURMpsoRZ5pzQt?p=preview